# Call java client having other java dependencies from PL/SQL function

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jar, plsql

I need to Call a java client `abc.java`

It is having other java dependencies on about 20 jars.

I need to call the client abc.java after compiling it to abc.class from PL/SQL function using loadjava.

My question is how do we load the 20 dependency jars and use the below command to load the class into Oracle and then call it from an Oracle Function.

```
loadjava -verbose -resolve -grant public -user myDB/myDB@orcl C:/myClient/abc.class
```

Do i need to manually load the dependency jars one by one and then execute the above command.

I tried loading the jars one by one like this:

```
loadjava -verbose -resolve -grant public -user myDB/myDB@orcl C:/myClient/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
```

Even if I add all dependencies I get `ORA-29534` Errors

Any help or idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `EXTPROC`. Learn more on http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg11rtn.htm

Comment: How do you know you are loading all the dependencies? ORA-29534 says that you are not.